# Artoolkit Utilities programs doesn't execute on windows 10

Tags: artoolkit

I am started to use ARToolkit and I want to work on normal image as marker.

I tried the first step to generate dataset from ARToolkit utilities but I couldn't open genTexdata program, its open and close immediately.

Any solutions? I'm using `windows 10`.

Answer (score 0):

ARTK SDK for Windows Desktop and Windows Store (including Phone) has to be rebuilt on Windows 10 Pro using Visual Studio 2015. I'm working on that.

But before this can be done you should know that the utility was most likely written with C/C++ and most likely built with MS Visual Studio 2013. This means you need the Windows VS 2013 C/C++ runtime redistributables. Try downloading and installing [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).